# Apps Script Forms, onsubmit values cant be used

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am creating a google form with a apps script manual trigger onsubmit like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453526/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-form-submit-responses-to-a-specific-sheet-in-a-spreadsh)

but when i go to see the execution information to see the answers there are just showed the
itemResponse value instead of the value itself. The code i am using is this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
     var formResponse=e.response;
     var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
     var test = itemResponses[0];
     Logger.log(itemResponses);
     Logger.log('test'+test);
}
```

when i see the logs of Logger i just see the following:
[image: Logs of execution]

why is it behaving like that? is because the server cant catch the response itself onTime when the form is submited? how can i solve this issue?

**Edit:** To clarify my question, what i want is to catch the response to store them in another place instead of the binded spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the event object for the onFormtSubmit trigger for a form.  If you want the event object for the Spreadsheet then use the other onFormSubmit trigger.

[onFormSubmit for Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

[onFormSubmit for Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

Comment: but i don't want to store the data in a spreadsheet, i just want to have the values of the response when the form is submitted to move them to another place, not necessary a spreadsheet

Comment: Perhaps you should submit a feature request

Comment: just saw the documentation you showed me and test it with the spreadsheet trigger in the binded spreadsheet to run a function there, i think your approach is the best, could you please give me docs of how to retrieve the data itself of the last submited answer?

Comment: if a understand , every time the form is submited it will activate the trigger in the spreadsheet, then i can run the function i want in the spreadsheet but i can't retrieve the data, i saw in the docs them are in namedValues but cant acces them

Comment: just solve it, i had to add the event as argument in the function, thanks you a lot Cooper